# How could I get the total amount spent on a particular item?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables (items table and price table)

items table

```
itemId   name 
 1        car                  
 2        boat                 
 3        horse               
 4        goat                
 5        book
```

price table

```
id      ItemId        Amount        Quantity
 1         1            200          2
 2         1            90           1
 3         1            230          4
 4         2            300          6
 5         2            120          2
```

I want to know what's the total amount spent on a particular item. Basically, I'd like to sum the data on the amount column for each item.

I wrote this query, but I'm not able to get the result I desire.

```
SELECT items.name, SUM(price.amount) FROM items
LEFT JOIN price ON price.itemId = items.itemId
```

This is what I'd like to obtain.

```
id      ItemId        Amount
 1         1            520      
 2         2            420
```

Thanks everyone, *Ethan Graybeal* answer helped solved my problem. I'm grateful

````
from price
join items on price.itemId = items.itemId
group by price.itemId
;```
````

Comment: Why is `id` for `itemid` `2` equal to `2`? None of the rows where `itemid` is `2` has an `id` of `2`. And what do you need `id` in result for anyway?

Comment: And why do you only show one table but in your attempt there is a join with another table?

Comment: You select items.name, however you say you want ItemId and Id, by Id you mean it should show rank? And what's the point of that join?

Comment: Okay let me add, the other table

Comment: I have done an update on the question

Answer (score 0):

Use an aggregate function (`SUM()`) and `GROUP BY` to group the result set.

```
SELECT items.itemId,
       SUM(price.amount) AS `Total`

FROM items
INNER JOIN price
USING (itemId)
GROUP BY itemId;
```

You could also get the items by name.

```
SELECT items.name,
       SUM(price.amount) AS `Total`

FROM items
INNER JOIN price
USING (itemId)
GROUP BY items.name;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select price.itemId, sum(amount), name
from price
join items on price.itemId = items.itemId
group by price.itemId
;
```

Using `group by price.itemId` will group the items together and sum(amount) will sum them.

This was the table I used to test

```
CREATE TABLE price
    (`id` varchar(255), `itemId` varchar(255), `amount` varchar(10))
;
    
INSERT INTO price
    (`id`, `itemId`, `amount`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 100),
    (2, 2, 75),
    (3, 1, 80),
    (4, 2, 110),
    (5, 3, 56), 
    (6, 4, 29), 
    (7, 4, 72)
;
                                                                  create table items
 (`itemId` varchar(255), `name` varchar(255));
                                        
 insert into items
        (`itemId`, `name`)
values
    (1, 'car'),
    (2, 'boat'),
    (3, 'horse') ,                                   
    (4, 'goat') ,                                   
    (5, 'book');
```

Which resulted in

```
+------+-----------+-----+
|itemId|sum(amount)| name|
+------+-----------+-----+
|    1 |       180 |  car|
+------+-----------+-----+
|    2 |       185 | boat|
+------+-----------+-----+
|    3 |        56 |horse|
+------+-----------+-----+
|    4 |       101 | goat|
+------+-----------+-----+
```

Comment: it would be better if you can provide some explanation for your answer

Comment: Thanks. ```select price.itemId, sum(amount), name
from price
join items on price.itemId = items.itemId
group by price.itemId
;``` did it